# Google Drive API shares the file with a different Permission ID than the one I requested

Tags: google-drive-api

For some very specific emails (`user2@example.net` in my case), Google Drive API returns a different Permission ID for the email and uses a different Permission ID when sharing.

Here are the steps to reproduce:

- When sharing a folder with user2@example.net, I ask GD API about its permission ID. (via https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/getIdForEmail)
- GD API tells me that it is 12345678.
- I then ask GD API to share the folder with this permission ID. (via https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert)
- But GD shares it with a different permission ID instead (00224878i - notice the "i" postfix in ID). Though GD UI still says that the file is shared with "user2@example.net".
- Now if I ask GD API to stop sharing with permission ID 12345678. It returns - 404 permission not found.

Comment: Please paste the code you are using for the last step,ideally with http request response.

Comment: @pinoyyid for last step I'm using https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/delete passing 12345678 as permission ID along with correct file ID. The code is (almost) exactly same as the Ruby sample on that page. The returned status code from GD API is 404. If you need, I can also paste original permission IDs.

Comment: presumably deleting permissionId 12345678i succeeds? smells like a bug. I suggest you carve out a code snippet that reproduces the problem and file a bug report.

Comment: @pinoyyid no, deleting with `00224878i` doesn't work either. It does return a `204` (instead of `404`) but the file is still shared. So basically a no-op. I'll submit a bug report.

Comment: bug reported - https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3886